# Increasing code readability without a decrease in performance (for this snippet in C)

Tags: c, performance, gcc, readability

In a fairly large and complex C program where running time is the first priority, I have to decide how I should write code pieces like this:

```
for (int i=0; i < md->global_grid[ic[0]][ic[1]][ic[2]].parts_num; i++)
{
    if (md->global_grid[ic[0]][ic[1]][ic[2]].parts[i].core.GroupID == RESERVED_GROUP)
    {
        md->global_grid[ic[0]][ic[1]][ic[2]].parts[i].core.GroupID = GroupID;
        fmd_real_t mass = md->potsys.atomkinds[md->global_grid[ic[0]][ic[1]][ic[2]].parts[i].core.atomkind].mass;
        for (int d=0; d<3; d++)
            md->global_grid[ic[0]][ic[1]][ic[2]].parts[i].core.v[d] -= MomentumSum[d] / (AtomsNum * mass);
    }
}
```

This can be made more readable and compact by using pointers like `pc` below:

```
for (int i=0; i < md->global_grid[ic[0]][ic[1]][ic[2]].parts_num; i++)
{
    if (md->global_grid[ic[0]][ic[1]][ic[2]].parts[i].core.GroupID == RESERVED_GROUP)
    {
        particle_core_t *pc = &md->global_grid[ic[0]][ic[1]][ic[2]].parts[i].core;

        pc->GroupID = GroupID;
        fmd_real_t mass = md->potsys.atomkinds[pc->atomkind].mass;
        for (int d=0; d<3; d++)
            pc->v[d] -= MomentumSum[d] / (AtomsNum * mass);
    }
}
```

But doesn't dereferencing `pc` take some CPU time? I usually use the first form and sometimes the second form but don't know which is really better. I use `-O3` of gcc for optimization.

I know that measuring running times and comparing them may provide an answer, but knowning what experienced and professional programmers think is always very helpful. In particular, merely comparing times doesn't tell why one form is faster.

Comment: Dereferencing `pc` may take CPU time, but then so does `md->global_grid[ic[0]][ic[1]][ic[2]].parts[i].core` ... Have you tried looking at the generated assembly to see if it is the same or different?

Comment: @jtbandes, in the first one, I have totally relied on the compiler for optimization. And no, I haven't seen the generated assembly. I'm not much experienced in assembly.

Comment: Maybe this will help you get started: https://godbolt.org/z/aTrWMh

Comment: First, you haven't proven the second form actually is slower.  *But doesn't dereferencing pc take some CPU time? I usually use the first form and sometimes the second form but don't know which is really better.*  If you can't tell, it doesn't matter.  **ALWAYS** write readable code.  Deal with performance problems **when they become BOTH apparent and cause real problems**.  Compromising readability just so you can remove 50 milliseconds off a process that takes three hours is worse than a waste of time - literally.  It makes bugs much more likely - and makes them harder to locate and fix.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I think you're right, though in this case the process may take about one week. Many thanks. It's great to see people who like to help each other. :)

Comment: A week. Can you thread it off?

Comment: @MartinJames, the code uses MPI to run on a cluster. I mean, on a cluster with, say, 100 total CPU cores, each run takes ~1 week.

Comment: @apadana oh, you are really up against it, aren't you:)   Best wishes for you and your data set:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the assembly in jtbandes' [godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/aTrWMh). Here is gcc's x86-64 assembly for the readable version of the inner loop:

```
particle_core_t *pc = &md->global_grid[ic[0]][ic[1]][ic[2]].parts[i].core;

pc->GroupID = GroupID;
fmd_real_t mass = md->potsys.atomkinds[pc->atomkind].mass;
for (int d=0; d<3; d++)
  pc->v[d] -= MomentumSum[d] / (AtomsNum * mass);
```

gcc is clever enough to see that the loop over `d` makes 3 iterations, so it unrolls it. It also sees that the lhs in each iteration is in the same array, so it efficiently stores the array address in `rcx`, rather than repeatedly dereferencing `pc->v`.

```
mov     rcx, QWORD PTR [rax+8]        ; rcx = pc->v.
mov     DWORD PTR [rax], ebp
pxor    xmm0, xmm0
add     rdx, 1
movsx   rax, DWORD PTR [rax+4]
mov     rsi, QWORD PTR [r11+8]
cvtsi2sd        xmm0, r8d
movsd   xmm2, QWORD PTR [rbx]         ; Load xmm2 = MomentumSum[0].
movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rcx]         ; Load xmm1 = pc->v[0].
lea     rax, [rax+rax*2]
lea     rax, [rsi+rax*8]
mulsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rax+16]      ; Compute xmm0 = AtomsNum * mass.
movsx   rax, DWORD PTR [r10]
mov     rax, QWORD PTR [r12+rax*8]
divsd   xmm2, xmm0                    ; xmm2 /= xmm0
subsd   xmm1, xmm2                    ; xmm1 -= xmm2
movsd   QWORD PTR [rcx], xmm1         ; Store pc->v[0] = xmm1.
movsd   xmm2, QWORD PTR [rbx+8]
movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rcx+8]
divsd   xmm2, xmm0
subsd   xmm1, xmm2
movsd   QWORD PTR [rcx+8], xmm1       ; Store pc->v[1] = xmm1.
movsd   xmm1, QWORD PTR [rbx+16]
divsd   xmm1, xmm0
movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rcx+16]
subsd   xmm0, xmm1
movsd   QWORD PTR [rcx+16], xmm0      ; Store pc->v[2] = xmm1.
movsx   rcx, DWORD PTR [r10+4]
mov     r9, QWORD PTR [rax+rcx*8]
movsx   rcx, DWORD PTR [r10+8]
lea     rax, [rcx+rcx*2]
lea     rsi, [r9+rax*8]
mov     edi, DWORD PTR [rsi]
```